# Insert buffered GEOGRAPHY Points into target table without duplicates

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014, sqlgeography

I would like to create a target table from a source table, which only contains unique/distinct points in the sense that there should be no points within the radius of 1000 meters from each other.

This is a starting point (simplified mockup using temp tables):

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Source') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Source
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TargetSeeded') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #TargetSeeded
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TargetEmpty') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #TargetEmpty

CREATE TABLE #Source
(
    Id INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    Point GEOGRAPHY
)

CREATE TABLE #TargetSeeded
(
    Id INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    Point GEOGRAPHY
)

CREATE TABLE #TargetEmpty
(
    Id INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    Point GEOGRAPHY
)

DECLARE @Point1 GEOGRAPHY;
DECLARE @Point2 GEOGRAPHY;
DECLARE @Point3 GEOGRAPHY;
DECLARE @Point4 GEOGRAPHY;
DECLARE @PointBufferDistanceInMeters INT;

SET @Point1 = GEOGRAPHY::STPointFromText('POINT(1 52.50)', 4326);
SET @Point2 = GEOGRAPHY::STPointFromText('POINT(1 52.51)', 4326);
SET @Point3 = GEOGRAPHY::STPointFromText('POINT(1 52.52)', 4326);
SET @Point4 = GEOGRAPHY::STPointFromText('POINT(1 52.52)', 4326);
SET @PointBufferDistanceInMeters = 1000;

--SELECT @Point1.STDistance(@Point2);
--SELECT @Point1.STDistance(@Point3);
--SELECT @Point1.STDistance(@Point4);
--SELECT @Point2.STDistance(@Point3);

INSERT INTO #Source
    SELECT @Point1
        UNION ALL 
    SELECT @Point2
        UNION ALL 
    SELECT @Point3
        UNION ALL 
    SELECT @Point4

INSERT INTO #TargetSeeded
    SELECT @Point1
        UNION ALL 
    SELECT @Point2

CREATE SPATIAL INDEX SpatialIndex ON #Source([Point]);
CREATE SPATIAL INDEX SpatialIndex ON #TargetEmpty([Point]);
CREATE SPATIAL INDEX SpatialIndex ON #TargetSeeded([Point]);

-- Identify Ids to be inserted
SELECT 
    Id,
    Point
FROM #Source WHERE Id NOT IN
(
    SELECT 
        So.Id
    FROM #Source AS So
    INNER JOIN #TargetSeeded AS Ta
    ON So.Point.STDistance(Ta.Point) < @PointBufferDistanceInMeters
)
```

I can identify candidates to be inserted from the #Source as set based approach in a (IMHO) efficient (?) way. I just do not get my head around on how to remove duplicates in the #Source table (duplicates in the above sense - with a buffer of  1000 meters). So ultimately, I would like id 3 or 4 to be inserted into #TargetSeeded (which one does not matter). Any ideas?

PS:

This is a correlated sub-query attempt which may be a solution:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Source') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Source
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TargetSeeded') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #TargetSeeded
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TargetEmpty') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #TargetEmpty

CREATE TABLE #Source
(
    Id INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    Point GEOGRAPHY
)

CREATE TABLE #TargetSeeded
(
    Id INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    Point GEOGRAPHY
)

CREATE TABLE #TargetEmpty
(
    Id INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    Point GEOGRAPHY
)

DECLARE @Point1 GEOGRAPHY;
DECLARE @Point2 GEOGRAPHY;
DECLARE @Point3 GEOGRAPHY;
DECLARE @Point4 GEOGRAPHY;
DECLARE @PointBufferDistanceInMeters INT;

SET @Point1 = GEOGRAPHY::STPointFromText('POINT(1 52.50)', 4326);
SET @Point2 = GEOGRAPHY::STPointFromText('POINT(1 52.51)', 4326);
SET @Point3 = GEOGRAPHY::STPointFromText('POINT(1 52.52)', 4326);
SET @Point4 = GEOGRAPHY::STPointFromText('POINT(1 52.52)', 4326);
SET @PointBufferDistanceInMeters = 1000;

--SELECT @Point1.STDistance(@Point2);
--SELECT @Point1.STDistance(@Point3);
--SELECT @Point1.STDistance(@Point4);
--SELECT @Point2.STDistance(@Point3);

INSERT INTO #Source
    SELECT @Point1
        UNION ALL 
    SELECT @Point2
        UNION ALL 
    SELECT @Point3
        UNION ALL 
    SELECT @Point4

INSERT INTO #TargetSeeded
    SELECT @Point1
        UNION ALL 
    SELECT @Point2

CREATE SPATIAL INDEX SpatialIndex ON #Source([Point]);
CREATE SPATIAL INDEX SpatialIndex ON #TargetEmpty([Point]);
CREATE SPATIAL INDEX SpatialIndex ON #TargetSeeded([Point]);

-- Identify Ids to be inserted
DELETE FROM #Source WHERE Id NOT IN 
(
    SELECT 
        Id
    FROM #Source WHERE Id NOT IN
    (
        SELECT 
            So.Id
        FROM #Source AS So
        INNER JOIN #TargetSeeded AS Ta
        ON So.Point.STDistance(Ta.Point) < @PointBufferDistanceInMeters
    ) 
)

SELECT 
    *
FROM #Source o
WHERE o.Id IN
(
    SELECT MAX(i.Id)
    FROM #Source i
    WHERE 
        i.Point.STDistance(o.Point) < @PointBufferDistanceInMeters
)
```

Comment: Maybe a visual example would be better. Do you have a big list of point and want select points and those need to be 1000 meters appart, Like trying to create warehouse to optimize the distribution process? Or you already have those point and want remove all the point inside each point buffer? The first one require an very big optimazation process, the second is very easy with `contain` function

Comment: You appear to be checking for distances between `#Source` and `#TargetSeeded` rows. Are you guaranteed that there aren't any pairs of rows _within_ `#Source` that violate your 1000m rule?

Comment: @Habo - please see PS - correlated sub-query attempt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this help?

```
-- Sample data.
declare @Source as Table ( Id Int Identity Primary Key, Point Geography );
insert into @Source ( Point ) values
  ( Geography::STPointFromText( 'Point( 1 52.50 )', 4326 ) ),
  ( Geography::STPointFromText( 'Point( 1 52.51 )', 4326 ) ),
  ( Geography::STPointFromText( 'Point( 1 52.52 )', 4326 ) ),
  ( Geography::STPointFromText( 'Point( 1 52.52 )', 4326 ) );
select *, Point.ToString() as DecodedPoint from @Source;

declare @Target as Table ( Id Int Identity Primary Key, Point Geography );
insert into @Target ( Point ) values
  ( Geography::STPointFromText( 'Point( 1 52.50 )', 4326 ) ),
  ( Geography::STPointFromText( 'Point( 1 52.51 )', 4326 ) );
select *, Point.ToString() as DecodedPoint from @Target;

declare @PointBufferDistanceInMeters as Int = 1000;

-- Merge the data.    
insert into @Target
  select Point
    from @Source as S
    where
      -- Remove rows that conflict with another   Source   row.
      not exists ( select 42 from @Source where S.Point.STDistance( Point ) < @PointBufferDistanceInMeters and S.Id < Id ) and
      -- Remove rows that conflict with an existing   Target   row.
      not exists ( select 42 from @Target where S.Point.STDistance( Point ) < @PointBufferDistanceInMeters )
select *, Point.ToString() as DecodedPoint from @Target;
```

Comment: thanks that looks great and is probably less clumsy then my original attempt. Can you please tell me the meaning of 'select 42' please?

Comment: @csetzkorn 42 is [the answer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phrases_from_The_Hitchhiker's_Guide_to_the_Galaxy#Answer_to_the_Ultimate_Question_of_Life.2C_the_Universe.2C_and_Everything_.2842.29)! It's a handy placeholder where the syntax requires a value or expression but it is never going to be used, e.g. inside an `exists` query.

Comment: Haha - how can I miss this (-: